# In JIRA, is there a way to force a template on tickets?

Tags: jira, ticket-system

It is very easy to create tickets on JIRA with almost no restrictions - which is why I am wondering if it is possible to force some kind of template or other limitation so that people create tickets with required fields.

I am unaware if this is possible and Google doesn't bring up much

Answer (score 2):

Field Configurations (which are applied through a Field Configuration Scheme) allow you to make specific fields required for a given Issue Type in a given Project.

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/changing-a-field-configuration-844500798.html

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is yes, but there is a lot involved in creating custom request views that require admin access.  You may find the following information helpful...

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/create-a-template-296093779.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of restrictions and also change the aspect of the screen the users interacts with by using the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) plugin, in particular by using the Behaviours feature of such plugin. You can also write Groovy code to customize almost every aspect of the form and do input validation/templating.

Answer (score -1):

There is no native functionality in Jira to create templates for issues. But you can achieve it with our **[Issue Templates Agent for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1229162/issue-templates-agent-summary-description-custom-fields?tab=overview&hosting=cloud)**. With this app, you can create templates for issues. When user opens a Create issue dialog, fields will be prefilled depending on your template configuration. You can also create many templates for the same issue type, so your users can select from Template field which template they want to use.

You can book a meeting with us to see this app in action: [calendly.com/appsvio](https://calendly.com/appsvio).

~[Kate](https://www.linkedin.com/in/katarzynazofiapawlak/)